# How to apply drawing to a dynamic texture instead of a sprite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm learning how to create dynamic textures using `CCRenderTexture` by following `Ray Wenderlich's` tutorial:[How To Create Dynamic Textures](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33266/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture-in-cocos2d-2-x).

I'm not really good at the subject especially when it comes to perform drawing with `OpenGL`. Please consider the following code:

```
CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureWidth height:textureHeight];

[rt beginWithClear:c1.r g:c1.g b:c1.b a:c1.a];

CGPoint vertices[nStripes * 6];
ccColor4F colors[nStripes * 6];

int nVertices = 0;
float x1 = -textureHeight;
float x2;
float y1 = textureHeight;
float y2 = 0;
float dx = textureWidth / nStripes * 2;
float stripeWidth = dx / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < nStripes; i++)
{
    x2 = x1 + textureHeight;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x1 + stripeWidth, y1);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x2, y2);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

    vertices[nVertices] = vertices[nVertices - 2];
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

    vertices[nVertices] = vertices[nVertices - 2];
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x2 + stripeWidth, y2);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

    x1 += dx;
}

self.shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionColor];

CCSprite *noise = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Noise.png"];
[noise setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO}];
noise.position = ccp(textureWidth / 2, textureHeight / 2);
[noise visit];

CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, colors);
glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, nVertices);

[rt end];
```

What this code does is it creates a dynamic texture, mixes it with a sprite and then draws lines across the texture. But i've noticed that these lines may be drawn only if `CCSprite *noise` has been added to drawing. Without the sprite the lines are not visible. So it seems to me that drawing is performed on the sprite itself, not on the dynamic texture. So my question is how do i draw lines (or anything else) on the texture itself without using a sprite?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the implementation of visit. You'll need to setup things such as the shader you are drawing with and the transformation matrices. That is likely why you can see the lines after drawing the sprite first since that data is already set before you draw the lines with the call to visit.